# Absolutely positioned logo in header scrolls with page

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an absolutely positioned logo in the header bar of my page, that keeps moving down the page when scrolled.

I *do not* want this behavior, I want the logo to stick to the top of the page and not cover other elements when a visitor is scrolling down the page.

Here is the page in question.

www.giracci.com

and the header logo code.

```
logoWrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

If you view the page, you'll see that it doesn't stay put, it scrolls with the page.

Comment: `position: absolute` and `float: left` are incompatible.  Pick one.

Comment: Your entire navbar is going down, did you noticed it? not only the logo

Comment: You are putting a class `fixed` in your nav id="site-navigation" when you scroll unnecessarily. Just don't do it, and problem solved!

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I didn't need both a float and a position. .I must have been exhausted when I posted this. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css file:
No need to change much of the code.
your navbar is adding fixed class when it is scrolled.

```
nav.fixed .logoWrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you prove this works - if you notice, the `visible-lg` applies `display: block !important` - which your `display: none` would NOT override...

Comment: I am adding `display: none` to `.logo-wrapper` and NOT to the `visible-lg`

Comment: Right, my mistake.  This is going to hide the logo always, though, and it does not seem that's what the OP wants....

Comment: Yes. this is a workaround. anyway, when we are scrolling on the page op has given, it is hiding its navbar and then making it visible again, so till that time scrollbar is way passed the visible window.

Comment: This worked like a charm. While it's clear I have some cleanup to do, this definitely solved the issue. Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 2):

First:
Copy the relevant HTML and CSS to your question.  There's MUCH more to the equation that you have not included.  You need to essentially include all the html up to the nav container, as well as the CSS, and indicating that your question includes bootstrap (I've already done that for you).

Second:
The reason that it's exhibiting this behavior is because one of it's containers - the `nav#site-navigation` - is getting a `fixed` class applied to it when you scroll, which applies the following styles:

```
nav.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And, because you are using the bootstrap class of `visible-lg` on the logo wrapper, it gets this style:

```
.visible-lg {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Which overrides the `.fixed` hidden property.

And, because the logo is inside that wrapper, that causes the logo to show up when you don't want it to.

So, you're using colliding classes, and need to straighten them out.

Comment: It also gets `.scrolled` applied to it which overrides the `visibility` again

Comment: Yes, thanks for this info, I was really exhausted when I posted this, so I should have been more complete with my code. Thanks for the excellent info, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would change these parameters in the css to display correctly the nav, to make sure that the menu items do not go below the logo:

```
.container {
  width:auto;
}
.container.nav-bar {
    width:auto;
    margin:0 60px;
}
```

After you've done this, if you want to **hide everthing when you're scrolling the page** (logo and nav), add this to your css:

```
nav.fixed.scrolled {
    display:none;
}
```

however, if you want that the **only logo is fixed when you're scrolling the page** add and edit these parameters on the CSS:

```
.logoWrapper {
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Note this is using the twitter bootstrap css framework, so your mods aren't necessarily as straightforward as you suggest....

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way around you can try. Because currently on your site it disappears at once so it feels like there is kind of a glitch/stutter, very slight. I needed something like this with my logo so I did it with JS. And it works like a charm. Here is the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(
  function () {
   var top = 75;
   var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentTop > top) {
        $(".logo").css("opacity", "0");
       } else {
         $(".logo").css("opacity", "1");
       }
});
```

Simply replace .logo with your .logowrapper or whatever. Hope it works.